# Connecting to SQL server using credentials in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

I ran into this issue where I **couldn't** connect to SQL server using the **credentials** . 
I **can connect** when using trusted connection = yes . 
Am I doing something wrong here ? Should something be added or concidered ?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                  'Server=1070010-01;'
                  'Database=test_DB;'
                  'Uid =sa;'
                  'Pwd =SDTK-1111;'
                 )
```

I have also tried replacing Uid and Pwd with username and password . 
I have also tried adding trusted_connection = no 
In all the above cases , I get this error :

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")
```

Comment: A trusted connection is the method used by Windows Authentication to connect to your database, Microsoft has a good article on the subject [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: It is already answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273146/python-pyodbc-connect-to-sql-server-using-sql-server-authentication]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pyodbc connect to Sql Server using SQL Server Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273146/python-pyodbc-connect-to-sql-server-using-sql-server-authentication)

Comment: Thank you .  It seems like it was a formatting issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this , string was not well formatted

```
  conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=1070010-01; uid=sa; pwd=SDTK-1111; Database = test_DB; Trusted_Connection=No;')
```