# How to create ODBC "DSN" for cross-platform testing?

Tags: windows, odbc, pyodbc

I need a simple ODBC test scenario on WIN which I can configure very simply and be assured it is working in support of another question at [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647069/what-do-i-need-to-have-a-script-communicate-with-odbc-inside-kvm-windows).

In a nutshell I'm trying to setup a PyODBC/Python script connection from Debian 10 (192.168.1.2) to Windows 10 in KVM/QEMU virtual system (192.168.1.12).

First, on the Windows 10/KVM, I see the  `ODBC Data Source Administrator` has a tab `File DSN` and `Microsoft Text Driver`. **Can I use FileDSN to test Python PyODBC connection to ODBC using a simple CSV file in place of Server??** (My research with ODBC only finds running server instances).

Next, what I tried:

- On Debian I installed [ODBC Microsoft driver for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).
- Shutdown the Windows 10 firewall, and I can ping in both directions:

  `$nmap -p 22 192.168.1.12`  # Deb to Win

  `> Test-NetConnection 192.168.1.2 -p 22` # Win to Deb
- On Windows 10/KVM I added a FileDSN with Microsoft Text Driver. I created a CSV file (`odbc_test_01.csv`) with simple header and one row of data (IE. `{'ID' : 1, 'NAME' : 'FOO'}`)
- Created a Jupyter Notebook to make testing easier. Here is my connection string and the results:

  ```
  cn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' # Driver installed above
                  r'FILEDSN=odbc_test_01.csv;'  # my attempt at FileDSN
                  r'SERVER=192.168.1.12;'  # KVM IP tested with ping
                  r'Trusted_Connection=no;' # explicit; use UID/PWD
                  r'UID=<username>;'   # Windows user name 
                  r'PWD=<password>',  # Windows user password 
                  autocommit=True)

  OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
  ```
- Tried `isql` from Debian command line with same string:

  `isql -v -k ''Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};FILEDSN=odbc_test_01.csv;SERVER=192.168.1.12; Trusted_Connection=no;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>'`

Similar pages here at SO:

[Authenticate from Linux to Windows SQL Server with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695990/authenticate-from-linux-to-windows-sql-server-with-pyodbc)

[Python pyodbc connect to Sql Server using SQL Server Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273146/python-pyodbc-connect-to-sql-server-using-sql-server-authentication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an SQLite database. Then I added [SQLite drivers for ODBC](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/).

Answer (score 0):

An ODBC "File DSN" is not a *driver* for accessing data in a file. It is a way to specify a DSN (connection information for a target database) as values in a standalone  *file* instead of in a standard configuration file on Linux (e.g., `/etc/odbc.ini`) or in the Windows registry.

If you need to "clone" a Windows DSN entry for use in a Linux environment then you may find my [dump_dsn](https://github.com/gordthompson/dump_dsn) utility helpful. It retrieves an ODBC DSN from the Windows registry and presents it in a form that you could use to recreate the DSN on Linux.

For example, say I had a DSN named "mssql199" on Windows and when I ran `dump_dsn.to_text("mssql199")` on it I got

```
[mssql199]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description=with UseFMTONLY
Server=192.168.0.199
Database=myDb
Encrypt=No
TrustServerCertificate=No
ClientCertificate=
KeystoreAuthentication=
KeystorePrincipalId=
KeystoreSecret=
KeystoreLocation=
UseFMTONLY=Yes
Trusted_Connection=No
```

To use that same DSN on a Linux box I would have to

1. copy that block into `/etc/odbc.ini` (or equivalent, for a "System DSN") or `~/.odbc.ini` (for a "User DSN") to use `DSN=mssql199`, or
2. save that block with an `[ODBC]` header instead of `[mssql199]` to a file, e.g., `/home/gord/mssql199_file.dsn` (for a "File DSN") and use `FILEDSN=/home/gord/mssql199_file.dsn`

---

**Edit** re: "Can I use FileDSN to test Python PyODBC connection to ODBC using a simple CSV file in place of Server??"

No. An ODBC DSN or FILEDSN on the Windows box will only be useful to connect *from* the Windows box *to* a data source (either locally, or on some other machine). We cannot connect *from* one machine (e.g., Linux) *to* an ODBC DSN entry on another machine